# na.rm and is.na give different answers

Tags: r, mean, na, na.rm

I've just come across a simple problem but I don't understand what's going on. I'm using R to remove NA values and calculate simple summary statistics, but is.na and na.rm are giving me different answers.

If I have a vector

```
> test<-c(NA, NA,NA, 1,2,3,4)
```

And I calculate the mean with na.rm = TRUE, I get the correct mean of c(1,2,3,4).

```
> mean(test, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 2.5
```

If I repeat the calculation, this time removing NA values with !is.na(), I get the wrong answer.

```
> mean(!is.na(test))
[1] 0.5714286
```

!is.na(test) gives me the correct values, but how is R estimating the mean here?

```
> !is.na(test)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: `!is.na` is not meant to remove  the na.values. It shows you which values are `NA`. do `test[!is.na(test)]` instead.

Comment: Just to clarify this even further, `is.na(test)` yields a vector that R interprets as `0 0 0 1 1 1 1`, the average of which is 4/7 or 0.57...

Answer (score 5):

`!is.na(test)` returns a logical vector. So, what you—in effect–asked for was:

```
mean(as.numeric(!is.na(test)))
```

which does produce:

```
## [1] 0.5714286
```

What you need to do is:

```
mean(test[!is.na(test)])
## [1] 2.5
```

Or, as Richard Scriven added:

```
mean(na.omit(test))
```

or

```
mean(na.exclude(test))
```

Comment: Or `mean(na.omit(test))` or  `mean(na.exclude(test))`